# не работает ns-show

Tags: angularjs

Есть страница где используется некий angular контроллер. В scope контроллера есть переменная

```
scopeVal
```

Кроме того страница подгружает внешний файл с константами. Файл выглядит так:

```
var calc_constants = {
    driver_list_type: {
        multidrive: 1,
        driver_list: 2
    },
```

На странице есть инпут

```
<input ng-show="scopeVal == calc_constants.driver_list_type.multidrive">
```

В таком варианте ng-show не срабатывает. Инпут невидим независимо от значения scopeVal. Я в консоли браузера пробовал достать scope и выполнить это выражение. Оно срабатывает и возвращает правильный ответ (true/false), обе переменные видны и определены.
Я взял это выражение и перенес в метод контроллера. Получилось

```
$scope.showInput = function() {
    return $scope.scopeVal == == calc_constants.driver_list_type.multidrive;
}
```

В таком варианте все прекрасно работает и ng-show делает то что ожидалось. Почему непонятно... Поясните плз?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В шаблоне не будет переменных из глобальной области видимости. Там будут только переменные из scope.

Вы правильно сделали, перенеся логику в контроллер. Так и нужно поступать.

Еще как вариант в контроллере можно было написать `$scope.calc_constants = calc_constants;` и ваш код в шаблоне стал бы работать.

Comment: благодарю, все ясно.